# Table formatting with a master column

Tags: tables, multirow

How can I format a table like this?

(1) It is empty at position (1,1) and (1,2);

(2) There are multirows from the second column, which are corresponding to the first *master* column.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create empty cells, simply provide no content -- but do provide a `&` column divider. Incidentally, there's no need for `\multirow` statements for this particular table.

A mock-up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more "open" look

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{clcc}
\hline\hline
       &                & B      & C \\
Box    & Initial height & $h$    & 1 \\
       & Initial mass   & $m$    & 2 \\[1ex] % a bit more vertical whitespace
liquid & Density        & $\rho$ & 3 \\
       & Molar mass     & $\mu$  & 4 \\
\dots \\ % fill in the rest...
       & viscosity      & $\nu$  & 9 \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```